# Expectations of order statistics of uniform RVs, via exponential formulation

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

If $U_1,\ldots, U_n$ are i.i.d. uniform random variables, then I know that the order statistics satisfy
$$(U_{(1)},\ldots, U_{(n)}) \overset{d}{=}  \left(\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i}, \frac{X_1+X_2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i},\ldots, \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i}\right),$$
where the $X_i$ are i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exponential}(1)$.

I know how to compute the expectation of some $U_{(k)}$ (it is $k/(n+1)$) by explicitly finding the pdf, but is there an elegant way to compute it using the reformulation involving exponential random variables? The following argument is suggestive, but incorrect.
$$\mathbb{E}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i} \ne \frac{\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i} = \frac{k}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Instead of choosing $n$ i.i.d. uniforms on the interval, choose $n+1$ i.i.d. uniforms on the circle and let one of them be the start point of the interval. Due to symmetry, expected size of each piece between two consecutive points is $\frac 1 {n+1}$ (as there are $n+1$ pieces) which yields $E(U_{(k)})=\frac{k}{n+1}$.

Comment: You can use exponential representation as long as you notice that $U_{i}-U_{(i-1)}\sim \frac{X_i}{\sum X_j}$ and then you can apply the same symmetry argument. Basically instead of looking for $E(U_{(i)})$ look for $E(\Delta U_{(i)})$. But the circle representation is more robust and illuminating.